# Parent dependency property is not updating child dependency property using Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have two user controls

- parent `Orders` that creates a list of anonymous objects
- child `Table` that shows this list in a `DataGrid`

**Parent XAML and CS**

```
public partial class OrdersControl : UserControl
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty OrderItemsProp = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "OrderItems", 
    typeof(IEnumerable<dynamic>), 
    typeof(TableControl), 
    new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public IEnumerable<dynamic> OrderItems
    {
      get { return (IEnumerable<dynamic>)GetValue(OrderItemsProp); }
      set { SetValue(OrderItemsProp, value); }
    }
}

...

<UserControl x:Name="OrdersContainer">
  <ctrl:TableControl x:Name="ChildTable" Items="{ Binding OrderItems, ElementName=OrdersContainer }" />
</UserControl>
```

**Child XAML and CS**

```
public partial class TableControl : UserControl
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProp = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Items", 
    typeof(IEnumerable<dynamic>), 
    typeof(TableControl), 
    new PropertyMetadata(null));

  public IEnumerable<dynamic> Items
  {
    get { return (IEnumerable<dynamic>)GetValue(ItemsProp); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProp, value); }
  }
}

...

<UserControl x:Name="TableContainer">
  <DataGrid
    ColumnWidth="*"
    x:Name="DataItems"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    CanUserAddRows="False"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    CanUserDeleteRows="False"
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    ItemsSource="{ Binding Items, ElementName=TableContainer }"
    MinColumnWidth="0">
  </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

**Scenarios**

- If I initialize parent property `OrderItems` in the parent constructor, it works fine, so **data binding works**

```
public OrdersControl
{
  OrderItems = new[]
  {
    new { Name = "A", Price = 1 },
    new { Name = "B", Price = 2 }
  };

  InitializeComponent();
}
```

- If I subscribe to updates from `IObservable` and update `OrderItems` property, I get a UI thread exception
- If I wrap initialization of `OrderItems` with `Dispatcher.Invoke`, nothing happens, child `DataGrid` stays empty

```
accounts
  .Select(account => account.Orders.Stream)
  .Merge()
  .Subscribe(message => 
  {
    Application
      .Current
      .Dispatcher
      .BeginInvoke(new Action(() => OrderItems = items));
  });
```

Why does child control is not initialized if initialization is inside `Dispatcher` call?

Comment: What `IObservable` are you referring to?

Comment: `account.Orders.Stream` in the last block of code has type `System.IObservable`

Comment: Why don't you use the `ObserveOn` method? Also, if you register a callback for the dependency property, does it get hit? What is `items` in your example?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I decided to set child `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property directly from parent code-behind. Still can't explain why setting parent dependency property doesn't initialize child dependency property with `Binding` in XAML.

**Parent CS**

```
accounts
  .Select(account => account.Orders.Stream)
  .Merge()
  .Subscribe(message => 
  {
    Application
      .Current
      .Dispatcher
      .BeginInvoke(new Action(() => ChildTable.DataItems.ItemsSource = items));
  });
```